# What is the name of the "branched function" (Maths) in correct English?

Tags: mathematics

Because I study Maths in another language, I don't know what do you call a "branched-function" in English. This is an example for what I'm talking about:

[image]

as you can see, the function f(x) is not like common functions like [image]. What do you call these functions in English?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical terminology in a purely technical context. It would be best asked on [math.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a piecewise function - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_function), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiecewiseFunction.html), etc.

Comment: Actually, properly speaking, it's the definition that's piecewise, not the function.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the function with multiple cases (each for a particular point or interval) is a [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) function definition.

The function is [discontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous) at $0$ (both left-discontinuous and right-discontinuous, since it has no limit when $x \rightarrow^+ 0$ nor when $x \rightarrow^- 0$).

Comment: Yes, it's a function without a limit. The example is from [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Example_of_a_function_without_a_limit) of the article.

Comment: looks like this site, unlike Mathematics.SE, doesn't support [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax).

Comment: @Theta30 I wasn't sure which concept almousawi was asking about, so I mentioned both. I've fixed the typo, thanks.